# Library (Lubridate)

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I am having a problem with the package Lubridate in R. I can install the package, but when I go to call the library(lubridate) I keep getting the error message below.

"Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

```
date, intersect, setdiff, union"
```

I have also noticed that when I install the tidyverse package that lubridate and all its functions are not being included.

Below is a screenshot of the error code below. If the photo doesn't work the code is below aswell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIdXo.png)

> library(tidyverse)
> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.2 ──
> ✔ ggplot2 3.3.6     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
> ✔ tibble  3.1.8     ✔ dplyr   1.0.9
> ✔ tidyr   1.2.0     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
> ✔ readr   2.1.2     ✔ forcats 0.5.1
> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
> ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
> ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
> library(lubridate)

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

```
date, intersect, setdiff, union
```

Comment: That is not a problem and it's not an error. It's just a message. It just is telling you that the `lubridate` functions of those names will be used in preference to the base functions with the same names. Also installing is different than loading. Installing pkg::tidyverse will not load any of its component packages.

Comment: IRTFM's comment and trickytanks's answer already explain what the message really means. Using the ```tidyverse``` message as an example: ```filter()``` will use the dplyr version. The other versions are still available by typing the package infront of the function: ```stats::filter()``` or ```base::filter()```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error message, it's just telling you that you those base functions are being replaced by functions from the tidyverse.

lubridate isn't loaded by library(tidyverse) (yet!). It will be soon though as reported in a [Tweet by Hadley Wickham](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/1558166157059919878) on 13th August 2022:

> It's been a very long time coming, but I just added lubridate to the core tidyverse. Would love it if folks would remotes::install_github("tidyverse/tidyverse") and let me know if it causes any problems #rstats

It's probably not worth using the Github version of tidyverse if you are a beginner to R.